# PHP/Javascript toggle function issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a small issue on a PHP and JavaScript page.
What I would like to happen is to have a table of categories where the user can toggle to get access or remove it.

I almost got it to work, except for one tiny issue. When I click to add a right, the fas star button does become black, and the PHP code behind does update the database, but when I click on a star button to remove the user right, the button remains black. The database gets updated when I click remove right, so no issue there. I have been trying many things already, but now I am a bit stuck.
Does anyone have an idea what causes it?

My relevant code :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <?php
    foreach($this->jobcategories as $jobcategory):
    ?>
    <th><?=$jobcategory->name?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($this->categories as $category): ?>
      <tr data-id="<?=$category->id?>">
        <td><?=$category->name ?></td>
        <?php
        foreach($this->jobcategories as $jobcategory):
        $jobcat = Categories::findRight($category->id,$jobcategory->id);
          ?>
      <td class="text-left">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info mr-1" onclick="toggleJobcategory('<?=$jobcategory->id?>,<?=$jobcategory->name?>,<?=$category->id?>,<?=$counter?>');return false;">
              <i data-id="[<?=$counter?>,<?=$jobcategory->id?>]" class="<?=($jobcategory->id == $jobcat)? 'fas fa-star': 'far fa-star'?>"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        <?php
        $counter++;
        endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript :

```
function toggleJobcategory(id,name,cat,counter){
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'categories/toggleJobcategory',
  method: "POST",
  data : {id : id, name : name, cat : cat, counter : counter},
  success : function(resp) {
    if(resp.success){
      var eli = jQuery('i[data-id="['+resp.counter+','+resp.jobid+']"]');
      var class = (resp.counter,resp.jobid)? 'fas' : 'far';
      eli.removeClass("fas far");
      eli.addClass(class);
      alertMsg(resp.msg,'success');
    } else {
      alertMsg(resp.msg, 'danger');
    }
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Likely not a PHP issue, Can you plase click edit then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve], at least of the HTML and JavaScript without PHP code

Comment: Hello, I tried to add a snippet. Although it is not showing the fas far stars, guess you can see what I would like to achieve. Add or remove right.

Answer (score 0):

What I would is not have the onclick handler inline and have the data that it needs as data-attributes.

This process will allow you to not rely on your PHP response to the have the IDs that it needs to control the icon, which is what I'm guessing is the problem. Inline event handlers are generally frowned upon as they are old.

**New Link:**

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info mr-1" data-jobcategory_id="<?=$jobcategory->id?>" data-name="<?=$jobcategory->name?>" data-category_id="<?=$category->id?>" data-counter="<?=$counter?>"
```

**New Click Handler**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-outline-info", function() {

  let id = $(this).data("jobcategory_id");
  let name = $(this).data("name");
  let cat = $(this).data("category_id");
  let counter = $(this).data("counter");
  let icon = $(this).find("i");

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'categories/toggleJobcategory',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: id,
      name: name,
      cat: cat,
      counter: counter
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      if (resp.success) {
        var class = (counter, resp.jobid) ? 'fas' : 'far';
        icon.removeClass("fas far");
        icon.addClass(class);
        alertMsg(resp.msg, 'success');
      } else {
        alertMsg(resp.msg, 'danger');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I tried your example, but it is not working (yet). Unsure what to do with this line :     <i data-id="[<?=$counter?>,<?=$jobcategory->id?>]" class="<?=($jobcategory->id == $jobcat)? 'fas fa-star': 'far fa-star'?>"></i>

Comment: @user12780319 you can get rid of the `data-id="[<?=$counter?>,<?=$jobcategory->id?>]"` as it isn't being used in my answer. What is it doing that its not working?

Comment: Well, I basically copy/pasted your code and got rid of the < i data> line as you suggested. Now, the toggle icons do not appear anymore as stars, but are just very small squares. Also, the "toggleJobcategory" function was not called on. Have changed your code a tiny bit (var class: (resp.counter,resp.jobid) ? 'fas' : 'far';) and now the function does seem to get called, but the response is always "right added", and nothing gets updated in the database anymore. :(

Comment: Had a look at XHR in page source. Looks like always the same data is sent to the function (the first), no mater which icon in the table you click.

Comment: I tweeked your code just a tiny bit. Works like a charm. Thank you so much !